# native memory is increasing while swap process

Tags: java, memory, websphere, hashtable, heap-memory

I have a function which works every hour in websphere server.

Shortly, the function reads data from database and swap data with old one. Until a new call of this function, it stores data in memory for to give fast response in online requests.

My problem is that, as normally at the begin of swap process my heap is increasing beacuse of duplicate data so end of the swap process I dealloced all temporary variables and my heap is decreasing. So memory usage before the swap process and memory usage after the swap process are same.

But native memory is (java native library memory) always increasing, it doesn't decrease at the end of swap process/ function or when I dealloce all temporary variables. I can not find what is causing it.

Here is my function

```
private void PopulateTL(String projectName) throws Exception {

    // Setting old models
    Hashtable<String, PreparedStatement> scoringFormulaMapCurrent = new Hashtable<String, PreparedStatement>();
    Hashtable<String, RSP_TL_Model> calibrationMapCurrent = new Hashtable<String, RSP_TL_Model>();
    Hashtable<String, PreparedStatement> scoringFormulaMapOld = scoringFormulaMapTL;
    Hashtable<String, RSP_TL_Model> calibrationMapOld = calibrationMapTL;

    // Getting new models
    String orgDbSource = masterConfigXML.getElement("Logging",
            "dbSource");
    String orgSql = masterConfigXML.getElement("orgSQL", "select"
            + projectName);
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(orgDbSource);
    Connection connorg = dataSource.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement prepStmtorg = connorg
            .prepareStatement(orgSql);
    ResultSet rsorg = prepStmtorg.executeQuery();

    ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (rsorg.next()) {

        String ScoringSql = "";
        double Beta1 = 1.0;
        double Beta2 = 0.0;

        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
        String strng;
        BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(
                ((Clob) rsorg.getClob("SQL_FORMULA"))
                        .getCharacterStream());
        while ((strng = bufferRead.readLine()) != null)
            str.append(strng);
        ScoringSql = str.toString();
        if ((Double) rsorg.getDouble("SLOPE") == null)
            Beta1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        else
            Beta1 = rsorg.getDouble("SLOPE");
        if ((Double) rsorg.getDouble("INTERCEPT") == null)
            Beta2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        else
            Beta2 = rsorg.getDouble("INTERCEPT");
        if (rsorg.getInt("SAMPLE_COUNT") < 5) {
            Beta1 = 1;
            Beta2 = 0;
        }
        String key = String.format("%s-%s-%s-%s",
                rsorg.getObject("FLAG_VADE_NEW").toString(), rsorg
                        .getString("SPLIT"), rsorg.getObject("BALANCE")
                        .toString(), rsorg.getString("CHANNEL"));
        keys.add(key);
        if (projectName.equals("RSP_TL")) {

            PreparedStatement psFormula = inMemoryConn
                    .prepareStatement(regulateScoringFormula(ScoringSql,
                            projectName));

            scoringFormulaMapCurrent.put(key, psFormula);

            calibrationMapCurrent.put(key, new RSP_TL_Model(Beta1, Beta2));

        }
    }


    if (scoringFormulaMapCurrent.size() == 0) {
        throw new Exception(
                "RSPSERVER: "
                        + projectName
                        + "refresh failed. Returned zero records from formula table.");
    } else {
        // set global models from current models
        scoringFormulaMapTL = scoringFormulaMapCurrent;
        calibrationMapTL = calibrationMapCurrent;
        System.out.println("RSPSERVER: " + projectName
                + " Refresh completed..." + "Size of Hashtable: "
                + scoringFormulaMapTL.size());
        //close old models' preparedStatements
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
            if (scoringFormulaMapOld.get(keys.get(i)) != null) {
                ((PreparedStatement) scoringFormulaMapOld.get(keys.get(i)))
                        .close();
                calibrationMapOld.remove(keys.get(i));
            }
        }
        // clear old models' hash table
        scoringFormulaMapOld.clear();
        // deallocate current models
        scoringFormulaMapCurrent = null;
        calibrationMapCurrent = null;

        prepStmtOrganon.close();
        rsorg.close();
        connorg.close();
    }
}
```

native memory increasing every hour :
[image: native memory increasing every hour]

- jdbc version : 10.2.0.1.0
- oracle version : oracle 11g 11.1
- websphere version : 7.0.0.37
- server : unix redhat 5.11

Comment: How do you know your "native" memory is increasing? Show some evidence.

Comment: I am using a monitoring tool for this. I added an image as evidence. @JimGarrison

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you are creating PreparedStatement(s) e g `prepStmtorg` you are not closing and this can lead to a memory leak. I also suggest

- you use a heap dump analyser (e.g. visualVM) to see where memory is being retained. I prefer YourKit as I find it easier than VisualVM.
- don't use Hashtable as it was replaced in Java 1.2 by HashMap
- don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder in Java 5.0 (still ten years ago)
- consider using RedHat 7.x as 5.x is pretty old. RedHat 5.x will be end of life`d next year, ten years after it was released.

I am guessing this was written by someone else along times ago, possibly nine years ago. It might be worth freshing up the code.

> native memory increasing every hour

I would start by ensuring you don't have a resource leak on heap, which is leading to a resource leak off heap.

Comment: At the swap time, I change old prepared statements with new ones. And I store them in a hash table. While swap, I close and remove and set null to old ones and allocate new ones. by the way, I changed hashtable to hashmap, and stringbuffer to stringbuilder but nothing changed. Still native memory is increasing. We are already considering upgrading redhat version but it is complicated because of some other reasons. By the way I dont mind its cause by redhat version @Peter Lavrey

Comment: @neverwinter where do you close `prepStmtorg`? You need to close them all, not just most of them.

Comment: Lavrey at this line, I am closing. ((PreparedStatement) scoringFormulaMapOld.get(keys.get(i)))
                        .close();

Comment: @neverwinter how does that close the first PreparedStatement?  You don't add it to that collection anywhere.

Comment: I store new prepStatement in memory, because if any webservice call recevied, I execute them. In every hour, I closed and set null to the old ones. But new ones must be stay opened for real time execution. se

Comment: oh I just skipped to close first prepstatement. I will try to close it. I will write the result. thx @Peter Lavrey

Comment: @neverwinter If you use a heap dump analyser you might find more of these and they are the most likely cause of a memory leak as these objects often have some off heap usage as well. e.g. GUI components are the same.

Comment: Lavrey I tried to close first prepStmt I mean that prepStmtorg. But nothing changed. Also I updated the code in my question. By the way you will be right about heap dump. Next step I'll try this.

Comment: I tried to change in memory db which I used. I used hsqldb (hypersql) instead of sqlite so native memory didn't increase. It seems like there is bug in sqlite. @PeterLavrey